# Basic knockout Save parent on child changes

Tags: c#, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have a basic knockout question:
I have an list of objects in this format:

```
 [{ Name: "Colors1", Values: ["red", "yellow", "blue"] },
 { Name: "Colors2", Values: ["red", "pink", "blue"] },
 { Name: "Colors3", Values: ["black", "white", "green"] }]);
```

I want to have a dropdown with the Name of the colors. And on selection change, the colors in Values should be displayed in text boxes.
When a color is changed in the textbox, the entire record should be updated immediately.

Here is what I have:

```
            <div> 
                    <select data-bind="options:myitems, optionsText:'Name', optionsValue:'Name', optionsCaption:'Please select a color', value:selectedColor"></select>

                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Color</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach:listofColors()?  ">
                            <tr>
                                <td><input data-bind="value:Value, event: { change : $parent.SaveUpdatedColors($root)?}" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
        //-----------------------------------   // 
               <script>    
                var  viewModel= function() {
                        var self = this;
                        self.selectedColorChoice = ko.observable();
                        self.listofColors = ko.observableArray();

                        self.myitems = ko.observableArray(
                            [{ Name: "Colors1", Values: ["red", "yellow", "blue"] },
                            { Name: "Colors2", Values: ["red", "pink", "blue"] },
                            { Name: "Colors3", Values: ["black", "white", "green"] }]);
                var getByName = function (items, name) {
                return ko.utils.arrayFirst(items, function (item) {
                    return item.Name === name;
                              });
                           };


   self.selectedColor.subscribe(function(item) //NOT WORKING
    {
        self.listofColors = ko.computed(function () {
            var selColor = getByName(self.myitems(), self.selectedColor);
            return selColor ? ko.utils.arrayMap(selColor.Values, function (item) {
                return {
                    Name: item.Name,
                    Value: item.Value
                };
            }) : [];
        }, this);
    })
                        })

    self.SaveUpdatedColors=function(fullRecord)
    { //logic to update}
                    }
                    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
            </script>
```

How do I proceed ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we start: *There were quite some syntax errors in your snippet, and quite some stuff that wasn't used at all.. I took the liberty to move some stuff around and delete some code.*

You want to create two-way data-binds for your color strings, but you're rendering plain objects with strings and arrays; those will not support updates through the `value` data-bind.

### Creating a second layer of viewmodels

The "knockout way" of doing things is to create a viewmodel for each item that you want to render and interact with. So for your case, I've created a `ColorItem` viewmodel. This item, for now, holds only a `name` and a list of `values` (string names of colors). For readability, I've wrapped the strings in a plain object so we can data-bind by typing `value: value` and don't have to use `$data`.

### Storing the selection and binding to it

Now that there's a list of `ColorItem`s, we can put a `ColorItem` instance in our `selectedColor` observable; note that you don't need to pick a property to store. You can store the whole item!

The `<table>` is now bound to the `selectedColor` using a `with: selectedColor` bind. This means the context of the table is an object with a `name` and `values` property.

### Subscribing to changes; storing a state

Finally, to be able to react to *any* changes in *any* color item, we compute a "state": a plain javascript object that reflects all the changes that are made. (Note that if you're planning to create a really big application, this might be too expensive).

For this example, the state is not much more than an unwrapped version of all your observable properties. By *getting* the observable's values inside a `ko.computed` or `ko.pureComputed`, knockout automatically creates a subscription to any future changes for you.

I've commented some of  the code in the example below. Let me know if you understand all of it and if it answers all your questions.

**Note:** Parts of the code assume you'll want to add additional functionality, such as changing names and adding more colors. If you don't need that, you can replace some of the `observable` and `observableArray` properties with regular values. You could also remove the "interim state" and only output your desired object format.

```js
// Our starting data
var colors = [{
  Name: "Colors1",
  Values: ["red", "yellow", "blue"]
}, {
  Name: "Colors2",
  Values: ["red", "pink", "blue"]
}, {
  Name: "Colors3",
  Values: ["black", "white", "green"]
}];

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  // Create ColorItem viewmodels
  self.listOfColors = ko.observableArray(
    colors.map(ColorItem.createFromData));
  self.selectedColor = ko.observable();

  // Computed state, holds name of current selection and list of items
  self.colorState = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return {
      selectedColorName: self.selectedColor() ? self.selectedColor().name() : null,
      colorStates: self.listOfColors().map(function(colorItem) {
        return colorItem.state();
      })
    };
  });
  
  // By subscribing to the computed state, we can trigger any other methods
  self.colorState.subscribe(function(newState) {
    // If you want to save to server, you'll need to rate limit updates
    // and abort previous posts
    
    // To convert back to your original format:
    console.log(JSON.stringify(
      newState.colorStates.map(function(itemState) {
        return { Name: itemState.name, Values: itemState.values };
      }))
    );
  });
};


var ColorItem = function(name, values) {
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
  this.values = ko.observableArray(values.map(function(str) {
      return {
        // By wrapping the string in an observable, we can bind 
        // the input's value to it
        value: ko.observable(str)
      };
  }));

  // Color items hold their own state: name and a list of strings
  this.state = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return {
      name: this.name(),
      values: this.values().map(function(valueObj) {
        return valueObj.value();
      })
    };
  }, this);
};

// A helper function to transform a {Name, Values} object in to a viewmodel
ColorItem.createFromData = function(data) {
  return new ColorItem(data.Name, data.Values);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select data-bind="options:listOfColors, 
                     optionsText:'name', 
                     optionsCaption:'Please select a color',    
                     value:selectedColor"></select>

  <table data-bind="with: selectedColor">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Color</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:values">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input data-bind="textInput: value" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed example. That did help a lot. So, if I subscribe to a computed column (eg:colorState  here) - do I get notified if ANY value in the computed column changes ?   I was trying to use this logic in a different case, and for some reason the subscribe on the computed column does not fire when a value is changed.

Comment: A `ko.computed` is, like an `observable`, "subscribable". (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/images/fn/type-hierarchy.png) Every `subscribable` value that is used to determine the output of a `computed`, will play its part in determining when the `computed` fires its own subscriptions. In the snippet, the computed state is a combination of all the `ColorItem` states, which means that if _one_ ColorItem state changes, the parent state will change as well. It's a bit hard to explain...

Comment: That makes sense and I was able to succesfully subscribe to the parent's save from the subscribe on the child observableValue. One thing I see is : even though I set ko.options.deferUpdates=true or extend teh computed function with {deferred:true}, the update is fired for every single change. Is there a way to mimic the subscribe of an observable value that gets fired only when the field loses focus ?

Comment: If you use the `value` binding instead of `textInput`, the observable is updated on the `blur` event. You could also use an extender on the computed to delay notifications (e.g.: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html )

Comment: That is perfect ! Thank you so much.. really appreciate your help.